# Forward declaration of class and still Error: Variable has incomplete type

Tags: c++, random, forward-declaration

I have defined two classes : (1) class `Point_CCS_xy` , and (2) `random_Point_CCS_xy_generator`. I would like to define a function in `Point_CCS_xy` class which makes use of `random_Point_CCS_xy_generator` class to generate random points on a cartesian coordinate system within a range `Min` and `Max`, both of which have been defined as `long double`. I have already `forward declared` class `random_Point_CCS_xy_generator`, however I get an `Variable has incomplete type random_Point_CCS_xy_generator` error on this line `random_Point_CCS_xy_generator rpg(Min, Max)`; and also this error `Member reference base type 'vector<Point_CCS_xy> (size_t)' (aka 'vector<Point_CCS_xy> (unsigned long long)') is not a structure or union`, on this line `Point_CCS_xy_vec.push_back(p);`.

**MWE**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<functional>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<deque>
#include<queue>
#include<set>
#include<list>
#include<limits>
#include<string>
#include<memory>

using namespace std;
typedef long double ld;

class random_Point_CCS_xy_generator;

class Point_CCS_xy{
private:
    long double x_coordinate_ {0.0};
    long double y_coordinate_ {0.0};
public:
    Point_CCS_xy () = default;
    Point_CCS_xy(long double x, long double y): x_coordinate_(x), y_coordinate_(y) {}
    ~Point_CCS_xy() = default;

    // copy constructor through construction delegation method
    Point_CCS_xy(const Point_CCS_xy& cpyObj) : Point_CCS_xy(cpyObj.x_coordinate_, cpyObj.y_coordinate_)
    {

    }



 // Copy and Mover Assignment Operators, 
 // also setters and getters, and a few utility functions come here inlcuding:
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point_CCS_xy& pnt);


// Problematic Function -> source of ERRORS
vector<Point_CCS_xy> Random_Point_CCS_xy(long double Min, long double Max, size_t n) {
        random_Point_CCS_xy_generator rpg(Min, Max);
        vector<Point_CCS_xy> Point_CCS_xy_vec(size_t);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
            Point_CCS_xy p = Point_CCS_xy(rpg());
            Point_CCS_xy_vec.push_back(p);
        }
        return Point_CCS_xy_vec;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point_CCS_xy& pnt) {
    os << "X: " << setw(10)<< left << pnt.x_coordinate_ << " Y: " << setw(10)<< left << pnt.y_coordinate_;
    return os;
}

class random_Point_CCS_xy_generator {
public:
    random_Point_CCS_xy_generator(long double min, long double max)
            : engine_(std::random_device()()), distribution_(min, max) {}

    Point_CCS_xy operator()() {
        long double x = distribution_(engine_);
        long double y = distribution_(engine_);
        return Point_CCS_xy(x, y);
    }

    std::mt19937 engine_;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution_;
};
```

As I am a newbie in programming, any idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The type must be complete by the time you actually use it (_e.g._ constructing a value).  Forward declaration will only help you specify pointer or reference types, not value types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type must be complete by the time you actually use it (e.g. constructing a value). Forward declaration will only help you specify pointer or reference types, not value types.

Your main issue here is that you're defining your functions inline in the class definition.  Instead of that, move them out:

```
class Point_CCS_xy {
private:
    long double x_coordinate_{ 0.0 };
    long double y_coordinate_{ 0.0 };
public:
    Point_CCS_xy() = default;
    Point_CCS_xy(long double x, long double y) : x_coordinate_(x), y_coordinate_(y) {}
    ~Point_CCS_xy() = default;

    Point_CCS_xy(const Point_CCS_xy& cpyObj);
    vector<Point_CCS_xy> Random_Point_CCS_xy(long double Min, long double Max, size_t n);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point_CCS_xy& pnt);
};

class random_Point_CCS_xy_generator {
public:
    random_Point_CCS_xy_generator(long double min, long double max)
        : engine_(std::random_device()()), distribution_(min, max) {}

    Point_CCS_xy operator()() {
        long double x = distribution_(engine_);
        long double y = distribution_(engine_);
        return Point_CCS_xy(x, y);
    }

    std::mt19937 engine_;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution_;
};
```

Then you can define the functions after:

```
Point_CCS_xy::Point_CCS_xy(const Point_CCS_xy& cpyObj)
    : Point_CCS_xy(cpyObj.x_coordinate_, cpyObj.y_coordinate_)
{
}

vector<Point_CCS_xy> Point_CCS_xy::Random_Point_CCS_xy(long double Min, long double Max, size_t n)
{
    random_Point_CCS_xy_generator rpg(Min, Max);
    vector<Point_CCS_xy> Point_CCS_xy_vec;
    Point_CCS_xy_vec.reserve(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Point_CCS_xy p = Point_CCS_xy(rpg());
        Point_CCS_xy_vec.push_back(p);
    }
    return Point_CCS_xy_vec;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Point_CCS_xy& pnt)
{
    os << "X: " << setw(10) << left << pnt.x_coordinate_ << " Y: " << setw(10) << left << pnt.y_coordinate_;
    return os;
}
```

Note that I fixed another error where you used `size_t` instead of `n` as an argument to the constructor for your vector.  As pointed out in the comments, that's actually incorrect to begin with because of the way you're populating the vector.  Instead, I changed it to reserve the required size before pushing elements.

Also you're missing some headers and using loads of others.  All you really need is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
```

Comment: I don't think `n` is intended in the vector constructor, because `push_back` is used afterwards.

Comment: Good point.  I wasn't reading the whole function, just fixing the syntax errors and guessing the original intent.  Will fix that.

Comment: @user17732522 My bad, I really appreciate it. You are right, I misused the  `size_t` instead of `n`

Answer (score 2):

You have to complete the definition of that class random_Point_CCS_xy_generator before you can use it in the actual function definition. Probably you will have to move the methods out of a .h file and into an implementation file.

Comment: @user17732522 and again -),

Comment: based on your answer, I kept the declaration of the `random_Point_CCS_xy_generator ` class and `vector<Point_CCS_xy> Random_Point_CCS_xy(long double Min, long double Max, size_t n)` in the same header file, and moved the definitions before the main() . The first error was removed, however, I still get this error `No viable conversion from returned value of type 'vector<Point_CCS_xy> (size_t)' (aka 'vector<Point_CCS_xy> (unsigned long long)') to function return type 'vector<Point_CCS_xy>'`.

Comment: That's because `size_t` is a type, so the compiler thinks you're making a function declaration.